# grant user on oracle

Tags: database, oracle, sql-grant

i have 2 users on oracle: bangdd and ivms

about ivms user, i can view some tables, as example:

```
SQL> connect ivms
Enter password: 
Connected.
SQL> desc voucher; 
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ACCREF                                             VARCHAR2(40)
 CARDNBR                                            VARCHAR2(10)
```

how to grant for user bangdd, can view table voucher?

SQL> connect bangdd

```
Enter password: 
Connected.
SQL> select * from tab;
no rows selected
```

Comment: Do you know about [GRANT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm) in Oracle SQL?

Comment: i am learning about it. i saw the intraction, i need to copy from ivms@localhost to bangdd@localhost, right?

Comment: grant means make authrize for user.

Comment: Is the Oracle documentation not clear? What Oracle version are you using? Is it 12c?

Comment: i am using oracle 9

Answer (score 0):

```sql
connect ivms

grant select on voucher to bangdd;
```

Then you can...

```sql
connect bangdd

select * from ivms.voucher;
```

If you don't want to prefix the table name with its owner, create a synonym.

```sql
connect bangdd

create synonym voucher for ivms.voucher;
```

Comment: i did it, but select * from tab, i dont see voucher table. i am reading about copy in oracle.